# Non blocking reading in Scala without framing

Tags: java, scala, netty, nonblocking

With standard java `java.io.DataInputStream` it is possible to read heterogeneous binary data like:

```scala
  val stream = new DataInputStream(???)
  val i = stream.readInt()

  if (i > 5) {
    val string = stream.readUTF()
    ???
  } else {
    val long = stream.readLong()
    ???
  }
```

it's ok except that it consumes the whole thread so will not be useful in high-loaded server.

**Is it possible to find/make some API for Scala which will look like this but be non-blocking?**

Of course there is a Netty's `ByteBuf`s but they requires framing like `LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder` to ensure that all data is already received before I will start to read it, and in my case incoming packets don't include length so it is not possible to know length of packet before completely parsing it. There is a `ReplayingDecoder` do exist for this case, but it's performance is not very promising.

Solution I'm thinking on is wrapping Netty handler in something like:

```scala
  trait NonBlockingReader {

    def readInt: Future[Int]

    def readUTF: Future[String]

    def readLong: Future[Long]

    //...

  }
```

And then it could be used like:

```scala
  val source: NonBlockingReader = ???

  val someResult: Future[Any] = for (
    i <- source.readInt;
    r <- if (i > 6) source.readUTF else source.readLong
  ) yield r
```

which is handy, good-looking and doesn't require framing, but I am wondering isn't it an overhead and am not I reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 0):

Scala does not offer explicit API for non-blocking file IO, however the plain Java API is exactly the right thing to use in those cases. You should look into using java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel or Java NIO Api.

Comment: `java.nio.*` and in particular `java.nio.channels.AsynchronousFileChannel` is low-level API. And I am talking about high-level api where I should not care about buffers and read and write indexes - just read Ints, Longs, Strings, and so on as I do in `DataInputStream `

Comment: what about `Futures` from `scala.concurrent`, it doesn't provide methods like readInt, readLong, etc., but you can write own wrappers for this methods. Second approach is leveraging of `akka.stream.io`, but it can force you to using buffers.

Comment: As I see, Akka streams also require framing.

Comment: yeah, what do you think about wrappers (readInt, readLong ...) over `Future`?

Comment: I think that it is what I am suggesting in my post, but I am in doubts if it is good idea, and if it is then maybe somewhere it is already implemented, isn't it?